# Raster and world file import to ArcGis, What are the map units?

Tags: python, arcgis, raster

**In short:** I thought the map units would be in meter or km, but this doesn't seem right. Are they in decimal degrees? Can this be set as an option in ArcGis?

---

Hi,

I'm cooperating with a researcher using ArcGIS to overlay some computer vision images on a map. I've created a world file to test the raster import in ArcGIS, but I seem to have gotten the scaling wrong.

I've created a jgw file to accompany a 1600x1600 pixel image which should cover an 8 by 8 meter square. I've managed to position and rotate it correctly, but the scaling is very much off.

```
0.005
0.0013043484005
0.00482687012982
-0.005
10.8090421
59.5502261
```

[image: Screenshot from ArcGIS]

**Update:** I tried, pretty much on random to downscale the image, and sent my colleague this file (Note that i miss-typed the number of decimals on line 1 and 4:

```
0.00000005
0.000000013043484005
0.0000000482687012982
-0.00000005
10.8090421
59.5502261
```

The resulting image looks like this, a lot closer to what I am looking for.

[image: The result using a world file with a random number of extra zeros after the decimal point]

I've created the jgw file using a simple python script reading a csv file of the corner positions.

The CSV input file:

```
Prosjekt,Felt,Kornart,Season,Date_image,BildeID,RuteID,OmtrentligHimmelretning,Hjorne,Koordinat-system,Latitude,Longitude
Multisens,Garder,SW,Harvest,30/08/2012,902,10,se,NedreHoyre,WGS-84,59.5501946,10.8092326
Multisens,Garder,SW,Harvest,30/08/2012,902,10,sw,NedreVenstre,WGS-84,59.5501637,10.809107
Multisens,Garder,SW,Harvest,30/08/2012,902,10,nw,OvreVenstre,WGS-84,59.5502261,10.8090421
Multisens,Garder,SW,Harvest,30/08/2012,902,10,ne,OvreHoyre,WGS-84,59.5502595,10.8091657
```

The Python script:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    data = pd.read_csv('pos.csv',header=0)

    # Latitude is Y and longitude is X
    # The corners are denoted as:
    # a ----- b
    # |       |
    # |       |
    # c ----- d
    hjorne = data['Hjorne']
    lat = data['Latitude']
    lon = data['Longitude']
    a = {
            'lat': lat[ np.where(hjorne=='OvreVenstre')[0][0] ],
            'lon': lon[ np.where(hjorne=='OvreVenstre')[0][0] ] 
            }
    b = {
            'lat': lat[ np.where(hjorne=='OvreHoyre')[0][0] ],
            'lon': lon[ np.where(hjorne=='OvreHoyre')[0][0] ] 
            }
    c = {
            'lat': lat[ np.where(hjorne=='NedreVenstre')[0][0] ],
            'lon': lon[ np.where(hjorne=='NedreVenstre')[0][0] ] 
            }
    d = {
            'lat': lat[ np.where(hjorne=='NedreHoyre')[0][0] ],
            'lon': lon[ np.where(hjorne=='NedreHoyre')[0][0] ] 
            }
    print a , b , c, d

    # Pixels per meter is 1600 per 8 m
    mPerPix = 8 / 1600.0
    scalex = mPerPix
    scaley = -mPerPix

    # The skew rate is sin( image width ) [m/px]

    rotationAngle = np.arctan2( b['lat'] - a['lat'], b['lon'] - a['lon'])
    skewY = np.sin( rotationAngle ) * mPerPix
    skewX = np.cos( rotationAngle ) * mPerPix
    print rotationAngle

    outfile = open('output.jgw','w')
#    Line 1: A: pixel size in the x-direction in map units/pixel
#    Line 2: D: rotation about y-axis
#    Line 3: B: rotation about x-axis
#    Line 4: E: pixel size in the y-direction in map units, almost always negative[3]
#    Line 5: C: x-coordinate Longitude of the center of the upper left pixel
#    Line 6: F: y-coordinate Latitude of the center of the upper left pixel
    outfile.write( '{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(
            scalex, skewY, skewX, scaley, a['lon'], a['lat']))
    outfile.close()
```

Comment: is isn't it a high resolution image with a custom origin?

Comment: Yes it is a high resolution image, 1600x1600 pixels. Should Cover an 8x8 meter square on the map.

Answer (score 0):

> In short: I thought the map units would be in meter or km, but this doesn't seem right. Are they in decimal degrees? Can this be set as an option in ArcGis?

Look at your first picture, bottom left. Obviously map units are in decimal degrees.
Map units depends on coordinate system and generally if you have geographic coordinate system like (WGS84) they will be in degrees, if you use projected coordinate system they will be metric or so.

If you need corner coordinates in meters, the solution could be transform your reference points( or layer you wish to use to extract metric coordinates) to  projected coordinate system used in your country. You can use Project, or Project raster tool in Arcgis for that.